# Инициализация(заполнение) строки другой строкой по определенным правилам

Tags: c++, строки, stl

Как можно заполнить(или инициализировать) string переменную на основании другой строки, пропуская определенные элементы, используя алгоритмы, итераторы? Аналог такого кода:

```
 string source = "abcdfgh";
 string temp;
 for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++)
     if (i != 2 || i != 6) temp.push_back('X');
```

Comment: Так вы же уже предложили решение

Comment: @selya я имел ввиду, использовать, к примеру, copy() или for_each() и аналогичные. Как сделать с помощью них я не смог понять. Если передовать функцию, то можно только изменять элементы. А как получить доступ к номеру элемента, условно, используя лямбды.

Comment: в примере, я так понимаю, опечатка и там `(i != 2 || i != 6)`, да? Не вижу, зачем тут могут понадобится итераторы, copy(), for_each() или лямбды...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, опечатка. Хотел узнать, как можно это сделать, как можно проще:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, пожалуй, эффективней и наглядней всего будет:

```
int a=2, b=6;
std::string temp = source.substr(0, a)
                         .append(source, a+1, b-a-1)
                         .append(source, b+1, std::string::npos);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     такой вас удовлетворит?
     #include <iostream>
     #include <algorithm>

      using namespace std;


    int main()
{    
    string res, source = "jkdtrifhf";
    transform(source.begin(), source.end(), back_inserter(res),
            [](char c) { static size_t k = 0;  ++k;
                         return c = (k == 2 || k == 6) ? 'X' : c; } );

    cout << res;

    return 0;

}
```